# position in a list with bind and wxpython

Tags: list, wxpython, bind

How can I determine the position in a list?
I have the following source code:

```html
   def __init__(self, parent):
      self.tickets      = []
      for i in list(range(15)):
         self.intRandomNum=self.getRandomNum(i)
         self.tickets.append(wx.StaticBitmap(self.panels2[i], -1, wx.Bitmap(self.ticketImages[self.intRandomNum])))
         self.tickets[i].Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.cardChoice)


   def cardChoice(self, event):    
      alert = wx.MessageDialog(self, _("Do you want to choice this card?"),
         _("Cardchoice"), wx.YES_NO|wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION)
      if alert.ShowModal() == wx.ID_YES:
         ret = wx.MessageDialog(self, _("This card:"+repr(self.intRandomNum)),
         _("Cardchoice"), wx.YES_NO|wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION)
         ret.ShowModal()
```

With the output of intRandomNum I only get the last random value. But how can I output which card I clicked on? With Bind, I don't think I can pass an additional parameter:

Answer (score 1):

Additional parameters can be passed using a `lambda` function for the `event`, in the `Bind` command.
Used in this way, it allows you to `append` parameters after the `event`.
Note that the `callback` function, has to allow for additional parameters.
Here the event `callback` function, provides default values for the possible parameters, in case they aren't sent (case in point, `flag3`).

```
import wx

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args)
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        button = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Click me", pos=(10,10), size=(100,40))
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: self.OnButton(event, flag1="1", flag2="2"))
        self.Show()

    def OnButton(self, event, flag1=None, flag2=None, flag3=None):
        print ("The Button was pressed")
        print ("Flag1 was set to ", flag1)
        print ("Flag2 was set to ", flag2)
        print ("Flag3 was set to ", flag3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    myframe = TestFrame(None, -1, "Button lambda event Test")
    app.MainLoop()
```

> Edit
> The above works for literal assignment but using a variable within a loop, the value of the loop count keeps changing and is retained as the final value.
> The problem being, that as far as I can tell, the lambda function evaluates the expression on execution, so it picks up the final/current value of the variable.
> Here I adjust the construction of the `lambda` to allow for this, with the on-the-fly value of ´y´.

```
import wx

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args)
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        buttons = []
        for i in range(10):
            buttons.append(wx.Button(panel, id = i, label=str(i), size=(100,40)))
            sizer.Add(buttons[i])
            lmda = lambda event, y = i: self.OnButton(event, flag1=int(y), flag2="z")
            buttons[i].Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lmda )
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()

    def OnButton(self, event, flag1=None, flag2=None, flag3=None):
        print ("The Button was pressed", flag1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    myframe = TestFrame(None, -1, "Button lambda event Test")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Note the `lambda` is created separately purely for convenience and clarity.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately it doesn't work:


   def __init__(self, parent):
      [...]
      for i in list(range(15)):
         self.tickets[i].Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, lambda event: self.cardChoice(event, cardnr=i))

   def cardChoice(self, event, cardnr):    
      alert = wx.MessageDialog(self, _("Do you want to choice this card? "+repr(cardnr)),
         _("Cardchoice"), wx.YES_NO|wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION)


When I click on the map, I always get the value 14, no matter which map I select.

Comment: The `lambda` function evaluates the expression on execution I think, so assigning a value which is not a literal, has to be done another way. See my edit.

Comment: Super! Thank you! It works. Don't you want to help me with my game programming? :-) (https://gitlab.com/horald/xcanasta)

Comment: @horald One of the benefits of answering other people's questions, is that sometimes you gain a better understanding of something yourself. `lambda` is a case in point. I may well find a use for this technique myself. Welcome to Stack-overflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers